# Django не подключается к базе данных с некоторых IP

Tags: django, база-данных

Django не подключается к базе данных на спринтхосте с некоторых IP. В доступе по IP на спринтхосте указаны все возможные IP адреса - %.%.%.% и непосредственно тот, с которого подключение не работает. В чем причина ошибки и как ее исправить?

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 633, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 907, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'a0558155_detailbase_test'@'2a00:1fa0:8676:8e80:7764:4f0e:bd98:7631' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 633, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 907, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/maggieeagle/PycharmProjects/detailbase/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'a0558155_detailbase_test'@'2a00:1fa0:8676:8e80:7764:4f0e:bd98:7631' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: Очевидно в том, что IP-адрес `2a00:1fa0:8676:8e80:7764:4f0e:bd98:7631` не соответствует указанной вами маске `%.%.%.%`, почему бы не указать просто `%` без всех этих усложнений?

Comment: Помогло добавиь отдельно этот адрес. `%` считает некорректным. Спасибо.

Comment: «`%` считает некорректным» — он на самом деле является корректным (я у себя использую), так что это видимо ошибка на стороне хостинга